# C# : DataTable capacity limited

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, datatable

In a C# program, I transfer Excel data to a DataTable, then display it in a DataGridView. But my data is truncated : the DataGridView stops at column F255.

In Debug mode, I found my DataTable has a record capacity of 256, and it matches with the place where my data stops to be copied from the Excel file.

Could I have done something wrong ? Is there a way to extend DataTable capacity ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTable rows have a hard max of 16,777,216 rows. Columns are limited by memory. One thing you can try is forcing your application to run as 64 bit by changing the build setting in the project properties.

Otherwise, you would have to buy more RAM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have 6Gb of Ram on my pc, and it doesn't work even with forcing 64 bits. I will manage my Excel file another way.

Comment: Yeah usually if you have it set to AnyCPU then it picks the optimal mode so that was just a long shot. DataTables also use up a lot of memory, you might consider a different approach to your issue or using structs to store your data in some other type of collection